# Pinterest API: Trouble Editing a Pin using api

Tags: pinterest

The edit pin using pinterest api is not working for me.But create pin is working fine.I have added my connection making codes below for your reference.I am making patch connection and also tried put.Can anyone check this?

```
String serverURL = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/<pinId>";
JSONObject pinContent = new JSONObject();
pinContent.put("note","The%20blank%20note");
pinContent.put("link","http://de-belles-images.blog4ever.com/blog/photo-651709-10928166-blog.html");
pinContent.put("board",<MY_BOARD_ID>);


public JSONObject patchResponse(String serverURL, JSONObject pinContent) {
        String inputLine = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        URL url = new URL(serverURL);
        String method = "POST";
        InputStream connectionIn = null;
        BufferedReader buffer = null;
        try {
            int setTimeOut = Integer.parseInt(PinterestConstructQuery.getInstance().getPinAppInfo("settimeout"));
            int readTimeOut = Integer.parseInt(PinterestConstructQuery.getInstance().getPinAppInfo("settimeout"));
            SocialProxy  socialconnection = new SocialProxy();
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection)socialconnection.openConnection(url);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(setTimeOut);
            connection.setReadTimeout(readTimeOut);
            connection.setRequestMethod(method);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(pinContent.toString().getBytes().length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.getOutputStream().write(pinContent.toString().getBytes());
            int returnCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (returnCode == 200) {
                connectionIn = connection.getInputStream();
            } else {
                connectionIn = connection.getErrorStream();
            }
            buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionIn));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((inputLine = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(inputLine);
            }
            buffer.close();
```

Comment: `String serverURL = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/<pin_id>";` The documentation is wrong.

Comment: Hi Zack, Now i got the response code 200 with response data but the data seem to be old one and it is not updated in Pinterest too.

Comment: I tested on the [Api Explorer](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/api-explorer/) and it looks like the endpoint works ok. Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the updated code.

Comment: Sorry for asking again  i too tested on the API Explorer but i got the following error response only  "error:Something went wrong, are your fields correct?"  and my pasted the calling url from API Explorer https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/<pin_id>/?board=<board_id>&note=Nice+Kitty&link=http%3A%2F%2Fde-belles-images.blog4ever.com%2Fblog%2Fphoto-651709-10928166-blog.html&access_token=<token>&fields=id%2Clink%2Cnote%2Curl . Did i miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue any longer as of this post date.

You'll do `patch` to `https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/{PIN_ID}/`

And then you'll send a `note` with the updated text `<YOUR-UPDATED-NOTE>` in the params along with a valid token: `?access_token=<YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN>&note=<YOUR-UPDATED-NOTE>`

Here is the documentation from Pinterest: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/pins/

Answer (score -1):

What error code and error message (if any) are you getting?

Is the code sample above up-to-date? I don't see where you are passing in the ID of the Pin to edit. Is `postContent` supposed to be `pinContent`?

Comment: Yes the postcontent is the pincontent..I have updated the code now.. The data is not updated in pinterest after invoking edit pin. For example if i change the note value it is not updated in pinterest.i am not getting any error response.the response code is 200.Hope this info is enough for you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Though there is no official word from Pinterest, it seems that PATCHing Pins doesn't work at the moment. I'm experiencing the same problem myself and developers [here](http://dirkgroenen.nl/projects/2015-08-12/php-wrapper-for-official-pinterest-api/) and [here](https://github.com/realadeel/pinterest-api) are reporting the same problem (and some additional methods that apparently don't work either.

This is the response body returned in my PATCH calls:

```
Unsupported Request

PATCH to http://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/501940320948839230/ not supported.
Reference #8.6502655f.1446998018.24cd9313
```

I've alerted Pinterest, and it would probably be good if more people did so. You can send them a message by going to the API Docs and navigating to "Get Help" in the left hand menu.

Comment: I actually just got word back from Pinterest saying they had fixed it. I still get the same result though so I just emailed them again.